Tween y coordinates of SVG path to animate chart transitions dynamically
I'm dynamically drawing an SVG path based on a data array (think linechart).
Would love to animate the chart transition when the data changes but this only makes sense for the Y values in my case.
The path is built
data.forEach(d => {
            path += `L ${pctCoordX(d.time)} ${pctCoordY(d.value)} `
})

This works great for the fixed values and is called whenever data changes to update the path.
Instead I'd like to have a reactive path that consist of something like
L ${pctCoordX(data[0].time)} ${tweenedY[0]} L ${pctCoordX(data[1].time)} ${tweenedY[1]}

but haven't found a away to make this work since it needs to be created dynamically and the amount of datapoints is not fixed.
Is there an elegant Svelte solution for this?

How does it matter that the number of data points is not fixed?

If it was I could just put the second code block I posted in my template and it would work.

Still don't get the problem, you can put data.map(d => ...).join(' ') in the template and you have a reactive path (as long as the parts are all reactive).

Maybe I'm just not seeing it, but how do you add the tweened values in there correctly? Can you share what exactly you have in mind there?

Your code is incomplete, so I still don't understand what exactly the problem is. What is special about tweened? Where does it even come from? A minimal reproduction that shows what exactly is stopping you would help.
